# Arbitrary precision arithmetic with GMP

Tags: c++, gmp, arbitrary-precision

I'm using the GMP library to make a Pi program, that will calculate about 7 trillion digits of Pi. Problem is, I can't figure out how many bits are needed to hold that many decimal places.

Comment: Maybe check out [this algorithm](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20010.5.shtml) if you don't need all the digits.

Comment: You don't know a lot of math, maybe start with something simpler. Computing trillions of Pi digits with a general-purpose library would take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 trillion digits can represent any of 10^(7 trillion) distinct numbers.

x bits can represent 2^x distinct numbers.

So you want to solve:

```
2^x = 10^7000000000000
```

Take the log-base-2 of both sides:

```
x = log2(10^7000000000000)
```

Recall that `log(a^b)` = `b * log(a)`:

```
x = 7000000000000 * log2(10)
```

I get `23253496664212` bits.  I would add one or two more just to be safe.  Good luck finding the petabytes to hold them, though.

I suspect you are going to need a more interesting algorithm.

Comment: 23 terabits for each one, actually... But, I just needed to know how many bits I would need, and I couldn't find an answer, but then you came along and gave, not only an answer, but an explanation! Bravo, sir, BRAVO!

Answer (score 1):

I wanna just correct one thing about what was written in the response answer:

> Recall that log(a^b) = a * log(b)

well it is the opposite :

```
log(a^b) = b * log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

2^10 = 1024, so ten bits will represent slightly more than three digits.  Since you're talking about 7 trillion digits, that would be something like 23 trillion bits, or about 3 terabytes, which is more than I could get on one drive from Costco last I visited.

You may be getting overambitious.  I'd wonder about the I/O time to read and write entire disks for each operation.

(The mathematical way to solve it is to use logarithms, since a number that takes 7 trillion digits to represent has a log base 10 of about 7 trillion.  Find the log of the number in the existing base, convert the base, and you've got your answer.  For shorthand between base 2 and base 10, use ten bits==three digits, because that's not very far wrong.  It says that the log base 10 of 2 is .3, when it's actually more like .301.)