# How to reduce C/C++ floating-point roundoff

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Are there any generally-applicable tips to reduce the accumulation of floating-point roundoff errors in C or C++?  I'm thinking mainly about how to write code that gets compiled into optimal assembly language instructions, although strategies on overall algorithm design are also welcome.

Comment: Please explain how 2/3 is imprecise in C/C++ but precise in assembly ;-) --- but you may want to look into things like the GMP library; see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414714/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-with-gmp

Comment: I've edited for clarity.  I'm not concerned about the absolute precision of floating-point numbers (which is limited by the IEEE standard and the fact that only powers of 2 can be accurately represented as floats), but rather the accumulation of floating-point roundoff errors in, for instance, loops that run millions of times.

Comment: First, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), a classic, a must-read. There exist a few algorithms for specific problems like [Kahan summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). That's the starting point. And then in C(++) there's a danger that some of floating-point operations can be carried out in higher precision than float/double, which has some troublesome implications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only trick I know is that when you're summing a bunch of numbers, don't do them one at a time - group them so that the additions are on numbers of approximately the same magnitude. To sum a huge array of random numbers for example, recursively sum by pairs.

Answer (score 6):

[Numerical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) is a whole field of mathematics and it isn't reduced to some tips one can apply blindly.

Answer (score 2):

People get PhD's writing about this stuff, so you won't get **really** solid advice here, just tips. One tip is to avoid subtracting numbers that are fairly close in value; that amplifies the effect of the noise bits.

Answer (score 1):

There are many small things you can do such as doing as many floating point operations as possible in a single expression and making sure that all inputs to the operation are converted into floating point format.  When switching between floating point and integers make sure to add a factor of 0.5 to the float before the integer conversion to ensure values are rounded to the closest integer.  Using doubles or long doubles will increase the amount of precision and thus lessen the significance of the rounding/accumulated errors.

You **will have** some amount of roundoff errors, so you really want to push them past the significance you're looking for.  One option for this would be using an extended precision floating point software library, such as the [High Precision Arithmetic Library](http://www.nongnu.org/hpalib/).  Using a library has a benefit of higher precision at the cost of slower operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable extended floating point precision of the FPU to use 10 bytes internally. This is what we use.

http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap1.htm

You can also sort numbers so that operations are performed on numbers of similar magnitude.

Comment: Is there any way to guarantee the full 80 bits are used and not rounded from C/C++?

Comment: My understanding (please correct if I am wrong), if you are continously adding lots of numbers, the sum will be left in a registry and use the extended precision until it is written back to memory.

Comment: That's probably true, but there are no guarantees. I think on some modern compilers the 80-bit registers are bypassed entirely and they use SSE instead.

Comment: @MarkRansom With some compilers (GCC), even when emitting SSE2 code, using the 80-bit registers (which are still there) is as simple as using the type `long double`. With other compilers (Visual C), `long double` is always 64-bit even when emitting historical stack-based FPU instructions.