# Transfer from Column Major to Row Major

Tags: c, algorithm, fortran, blas

I'm trying to convert an algorithm, which is written in Fortran and uses column major ordering to C using row major ordering. 
The algorithm uses gemv blas calls.

I altered the calls for row major layout as in the cblas interface:

- toggle transpose flag
- swap of M and N
- alter leading dimensions

But the algorithm doesn't behave equal. I'm getting different results. 
I created a minimal sample which shows the behaviour.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dgemv_( const char * t, const int * m, const int * n, const double * alpha, const double * A, const int *lda, const double * X, const int * incx, 
    const double * beta, double * Y, const int *incy );

int main()
{
    const int M = 2, N = 2;
    const int one = 1;
    const double alpha = -1.0, beta = 1.0;
    const char trans = 'T';
    const char noTrans = 'N';

    double Yc[4] = { 0x1.42c7bd3b6266cp+4, 0x1.6c6ff393729dp+4, 0x1.acee1f3938c0bp-2, 0x1.b0cd5ba440d93p+0 };
    double Yr[4] = { 0x1.42c7bd3b6266cp+4, 0x1.acee1f3938c0bp-2, 0x1.6c6ff393729dp+4, 0x1.b0cd5ba440d93p+0 };

    double A[2] = { 0x1.11acee560242ap-2, 0x1p+0 };

    double Bc[2] = { 0x1.8p+2, 0x1.cp+2 };
    double Br[2] = { 0x1.8p+2, 0x1.cp+2 };

    dgemv_( &noTrans, &M, &N, &alpha, Yc, &M, A, &one, &beta, Bc, &one );

    printf("Result Column Major\n");
    printf("%a %a\n", Bc[0], Bc[1]);

    dgemv_( &trans, &N, &M, &alpha, Yr, &N, A, &one, &beta, Br, &one );

    printf("Result Row Major\n");
    printf("%a %a\n", Br[0], Br[1]);
}
```

I used the format string %a to get the hexadecimal representation of the values to compare them. The resulting vector using column major version looks like:

```
0x1.8402515a17beap-3 -0x1.8e67415bce3aep-1
```

While to one in row major looks like these:

```
0x1.8402515a17bep-3 -0x1.8e67415bce3bp-1
```

How is this explainable and what can be done, to make the algorithms works equal?

Comment: Do you really find hexadecimal numbers easier to read? I have no idea how much they differ. Probably that is just a small rounding error.

Answer (score 4):

If the results are compared with decimal representation

```
double x = 0x1.8402515a17beap-3, y = 0x1.8402515a17bep-3;
printf( "%40.30f\n", x );
printf( "%40.30f\n", y );
printf( "%40.30f\n", x - y );
```

they agree up to 15 significant figures

```
    0.189457545816338168709336287066
    0.189457545816337891153580130776
    0.000000000000000277555756156289
```

so the difference seems sufficiently small for double-precision calculation with `double`.  As for `-0x1.8e67415bce3aep-1` and `-0x1.8e67415bce3bp-1`, the difference is also below 1.0e-15.

```
   -0.778131525475250773737911913486
   -0.778131525475250995782516838517
    0.000000000000000222044604925031
```

To obtain even better agreement, quadruple (or higher) precision is probably necessary.

Comment: This page may also be useful http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/

Comment: I know that the difference in this example is really small, but this is just one small part of the algorithm. Before this gemv call the results are binary identical.
Over the iterations the failure will sum up so that the results will really differ.
Is there something I didn't mentioned while transfering the algorithm from column to row major layout?

Comment: Hi @Schrigga I think numerical calculations with finite precision are more or less affected by round-off errors and their accumulation, the degree of which depends on the way a calculation is done (for example, http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys317/lectures/roundoff.html). If the error seems to grow as the iteration proceeds, it may be useful to edit the Question to add more information (or even post a new question focusing on the algorithm part).

Comment: @Schrigga These pages may also be useful   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487659/how-to-reduce-c-c-floating-point-roundoff  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Schrigga As for matrix transpose, I guess dgemv() may perform a different order of arithmetic operations (or algorithms) internally depending "T" or "N", which can result in slightly different results (within round-off errors).